# Javascript Check User Input without Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `javascript` and I want to change an html code based on what is in the text box. But I have values that are passed from the previous page and put into the inputs. But the html code does not trigger because it uses a `.keyup` function and I want to know if it was possible to execute javascript without a keyup function and without altering the text.

My code

```
<div>
<label>Name</label><br />
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange="NameCheck();"/>
<span class="error" id="namecheck"></span>
    </div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#name").keyup(NameCheck);
 });

   function NameCheck() {
   var password = $("#name").val();

   if (password == ""){
    $("#namecheck").html("Name is Blank");
     $("#namecheck").css('color', 'red');
    return false;
   }else{
    $("#namecheck").html("Name Is Valid");
     $("#namecheck").css('color', 'green');
    return true;
   }
   }
```

Comment: So, you want to validate the entered name/password on page-load?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have values that are being passed from the previous page and into the inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bWgEm/), it is a working example of what you want! note that you don't need the `onchange` method, because your using jquery's `keyup`

so your code should be like this:
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#name").keyup(function () {
        NameCheck();
    });
    NameCheck();
});

function NameCheck() {
        var password = $("#name").val();

        if (password == "") {
            $("#namecheck").html("Name is Blank");
            $("#namecheck").css('color', 'red');
        } else {
            $("#namecheck").html("Name Is Valid");
            $("#namecheck").css('color', 'green');
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <span class="error" id="namecheck"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i have so far, I want it to be like the [Twitter](https://twitter.com/) registration where you input your name and email and when you hit register it puts the name you entered on the previous page into the actual signup page. And the html changes on pageload without actually altering the input

Comment: I think my solution checks the input at page load and the validation works immediately, does it not? if yes please mark it as an answer! :) Now as for your comment I think it is a different issue, are you asking about a server side solution or what exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Though you should really restructure your code to not use globals, if you want to call `NameCheck()` on page load just call it after your event binding, like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#name").keyup(NameCheck);
  NameCheck();
});
```

Comment: I have the `$(document).ready(function () {` and i called for the function but the html code doesn't display unless i alter what is inside of the input.

Comment: In your `$(document).ready()` you don't have a call to `NameCheck()`, you just have `$("#name").keyup(NameCheck)`.